# Как подключать файл php на смену языка?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть два файла:

```
language/ua.php  
language/en.php
```

Хочу сделать что-то такое:

```
$("#go-uk").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".include_lang_bl").load( "language/ua.php" );   
})

$("#go-en").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".include_lang_bl").load( "language/en.php" );  
})
```

Но что-то не очень получается.

Comment: ошибка какая? Что во вкладке Network XHR ?

Comment: @EVG Файл вроде подключаетса только контент не меняетса почемуто

Comment: и что возвращает файл?

Comment: @EVG http://prntscr.com/l24f1q

Comment: @EVG что не так? почему контент не меняетса

Comment: Так а Response какой!?